# Mirations in sequelize from existing models in nodejs

Tags: node.js, migration, sequelize.js

I am in need of generating **migration** from **existing** **models**, So that don't need to create models again. Is there any way to do this in **SequelizeJs** with nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

It's there in the documentation.

Create a folder `migrations`, put a skeleton in:

```
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    // logic for transforming into the new state
  },

  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    // logic for reverting the changes
  }
}
```

Now you can manipulate tables like so:

```
queryInterface.createTable(
  'nameOfTheNewTable',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    },
  },
  {
    engine: 'MYISAM', // default: 'InnoDB'
    charset: 'latin1' // default: null
  }
)
```

Run `sequelize db:migrate` to do the migrations.

Full documentation [HERE](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/).

Comment: Are you here meant to create by only create a file in migration with model name and put data like above?? and what about association of model?

Comment: This just defines the table data, not associations or the model itself.

Comment: If i create migrations manually ,does that effect anywhere else also?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking and what this has to do with the original question.

Comment: Your answer is not clear to me. Are you saying that firstly i create migration with specified name and after that just manipulate tables according to my requirement?